# Динамическая инициализация в с++

Tags: c++, инициализация

Недавно вычитал вот [тут](https://coderoad.ru/5945897/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-c), что **одна и та же переменная может быть динамически инициализирована после того, как она была статически инициализирована**. Верно ли это? Если да, то разве можно инициализировать переменную 2 раза? Получается, что во время второй инициализации происходит не инициализация а присваивание

Comment: Там же четко сформулировано:  `Динамическая инициализация-это та, в которой значение инициализации не известно во время компиляции. Он вычисляется во время выполнения для инициализации переменной. ` и дальше `Статическая инициализация : либо нулевая инициализация, либо инициализация с постоянным выражением Любая другая инициализация является динамической инициализацией.`
И речь идет только об ИНИЦИАЛИЗАЦИИ, а присваивание это уже после инициализации

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, так в том то и заключается вопрос, разве можно инициализировать переменную два раза? Неужели сразу две инициализации могут происходить при создании переменной? Всегда думал, что переменную можно инициализировать только один раз

Comment: Так речь и идет об одном разе, либо статически, если известно чем инициализировать во время работы компилятора, либо динамически, если во время компиляции непонятно чем и как, и тогда процесс инициализации откладывает до выполнения кода, но сама инициализация происходит один раз (либо, либо)

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, может я вас неправильно понял, но: `Это означает, что в соответствии с §3.6.2.1 он инициализируется до 0 на фазе статической инициализации, которая происходит до любой другой инициализации . Затем позже, во время выполнения, он динамически инициализируется значением, возвращаемым функцией factorial()`. По словам этого человека выходит так, что происходит 2 инициализации

Comment: Только для статических переменных `static int c;//this is also static initialization (with zero)!`

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, на всякий случай уточню, статических в плане продолжительности хранения? То есть глобальная переменная `int a`(она имеет статическую продолжительность хранения), тоже получит "двойную инициализацию" ?

Comment: Думаю, да. А вы проверьте, это же не сложно. Объявите `static int i` и просто `int j` и где-нибудь в main.cpp посмотрите их значения. У обоих должен быть 0

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, посмотрел в отладчике, да так и есть,. Спасибо за помощь :)

Comment: Пожалуйста. Ох уж эти программисты-юристы-буквоеды :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Недавно вычитал вот тут, что одна и та же переменная может быть динамически инициализирована после того, как она была статически инициализирована. Верно ли это? Если да, то разве можно инициализировать переменную 2 раза?

Да, верно. Да, переменная может быть инициализирована дважды.

Это скорее вопрос терминологический: правильно ли называть вторую инициализацию инициализацией... Стандарт языка говорит, что в начале выполнения программы переменные со статическим классом хранения подвергаются статической инициализации (*static initialization*). Затем в процессе выполнения программы они могут быть дополнительно подвержены динамической инициализации (*dynamic initialization*).

Факт двойной инициализации вполне можно обнаружить на практике. [basic.start.static/Note 2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.static#note-2):

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

inline double fd() { return 1.0; }
extern double d1;
double d2 = d1;     // unspecified:
                    // may be statically initialized to 0.0 or
                    // dynamically initialized to 0.0 if d1 is
                    // dynamically initialized, or 1.0 otherwise
double d1 = fd();   // may be initialized statically or dynamically to 1.0

int main() {
    cout << "d1: " << d1 << endl;
    cout << "d2: " << d2 << endl;
}
```

Вывод данной программы ([g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4cddbbb257dc63b9), [clang](https://ideone.com/5Oc0F8)):

```
d1: 1
d2: 0
```

Наблюдаемое поведение можно объяснить следующим образом.

1. Переменные `d1` и `d2` статически инициализируются нулём.
2. Затем переменная `d2` динамически инициализируется значением переменной `d1` (`double d2 = d1;`).
3. Наконец, переменная `d1` динамически инициализируется результатом вызова функции `fd` (`double d1 = fd();`).

---

Впрочем, тут не всё так просто. Если не брать во внимание переменную `d2`, то код

```
inline double fd() { return 1.0; }
double d1 = fd();
```

в общем-то эквивалентен такому коду:

```
double d1 = 1.0;
```

Динамическую инициализацию переменной `d1` можно заменить статической инициализацией, при этом значение переменной `d1` не изменится. Стандарт языка явно разрешает делать такую замену. См.: [basic.start.static/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.static#3). На этапе статической инициализации переменной `d1` может быть присвоено значение `1.0`, а не `0.0`. Т.е. наблюдаемое поведение может быть и таким:

1. Переменная `d1` статически инициализируется значением `1.0`, а переменная `d2` статически инициализируется значением `0.0`.
2. Затем переменная `d2` динамически инициализируется значением переменной `d1` (т.е. также принимает значение `1.0`).

Наконец, так как переменной `d2` в конечном итоге присваивается некоторое вполне конкретное значение, известное на этапе компиляции, то она, также как и переменная `d1`, может не подвергаться динамической инициализации, а только статической.

Как-то так.